# Custom HttpMessageConverter in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When implementing RESTful API I wrap all my data in an object so it looks like this.

```
{error: null, code: 200, data: {...actual data...}}
```

This results in repetitive code I use everywhere to wrap data:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Result<List<BookShortDTO>> books() {

    List<Book> books = booksDao.readBooks();
    return Result.ok(books); // this gets repeated everywhere
}
```

So the question is how do I modify this (maybe with use of custom HttpMessageConverter maybe some other ways?) to just return booksDao.readBooks() and to get it wrapped automatically.

Comment: Add jackson 2+ to the class path to serialize and deserialize JSON with `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: It's already there. The question is that I want it to wrap my outcome in Result object automatically so I won't have to write return Result.ok(books); in every response

Comment: By `Result.ok`, should we assume that you have other `Result` methods for different error codes and messages?

Comment: Well, yes. For example I can return Result.forbidden() if user doesn't have appropriate right

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like @Ralph suggested you can use a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` to wrap your handlers return value.

The easiest way to achieve this is by extending `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` and alter it's behavior a bit. Best is to create a custom annotation to mark your handler methods with. This will make sure your `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` will be called instead of others included by `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` by default.

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ResultResponseBody {}
```

Here is a simple implementation of the custom `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` named `ResultResponseHandlerMethodProcessor` which will support values returned from methods annotated with `ResultResponseBody`. It's pretty simple. Just override the `supportsReturnType()` and `handleReturnValue()` methods to suit your needs (wrap the return value into a `Result` type).

```
public class ResultResponseHandlerMethodProcessor extends RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor {
    public ResultResponseHandlerMethodProcessor(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters) {
        super(messageConverters);
    }

    public ResultResponseHandlerMethodProcessor(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters, final ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager) {
        super(messageConverters, contentNegotiationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsReturnType(final MethodParameter returnType) {
        return returnType.getMethodAnnotation(ResultResponseBody.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleReturnValue(final Object returnValue, final MethodParameter returnType, final ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, final NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws IOException, HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
        super.handleReturnValue(Result.ok(returnValue), returnType, mavContainer, webRequest);
    }
}
```

The only thing left is to add this class to the list of custom `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`s and provide it with a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` instance.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(final List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers) {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        returnValueHandlers.add(new ResultResponseHandlerMethodProcessor(messageConverters));
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not need to override `supportsReturnType` as long it does the same like the super class - or did I missed something?

Comment: @Ralph If you want to support the custom annotation you do. For anything else I guess you're right.

Comment: @Bart - sorry, you are absolutely right - You described it in the text above "Best is to create a custom annotation to mark your handler methods with..."

Comment: @Ralph Come to think of it. If the `supportsReturnType` is the same as `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` then `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` will be the one to handle the return value. Not the custom handler.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to try and convince you that what you are doing is right and does not require any changes.

As you've posted in the comments to your question, you have a number of different `Result` methods which set the error message, the code, and the data. Something like

```
Result.ok(data)
Result.forbidden()
Result.badRequest("<Something> caused a syntax error.") 
Result.notModified("The entity was not modified.")
```

I'm assuming these methods are meant to map to the various [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), but with custom error messages.

Your `@Controller` handler methods are meant to handle a request and prepare a response. That's what your method is currently doing and **it is very explicit about what it does**. The logic about what the `Result` should be belongs to the handler method, not a `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`, like others are proposing.

I would even suggest using [`ResponseEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) instead of `@ResponseBody`. You can return a `ResponseEntity` and set the HTTP response headers and status code explicitly. You would also set the response body.

Something like

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(Result.ok(books));
```

In this case, the default status code is 200.

But if you wanted to use

```
return Result.forbidden();
```

you would use

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(Result.forbidden(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
```

Spring will use the same `HttpMessageConverter` to convert your `Result` into JSON, but here you will have more control over the HTTP response.

Answer (score 2):

I think, rather than changing the message converters (which would work), I would use an AOP approach - around advice on all the relevant controller methods would be quite easy to set up. It would also give you a nicer programming model, and finer grained control of which methods are intercepted.

Comment: Can you please provide some example?

Comment: Spring MVC's `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` provides a list of `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`s so you don't have to resort to AOP. I would use AOP only if it's the last possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html?is-external=true) to replace the result.

The key point is: to replace the return value before delegating the (modified) retunr value to the serialisation.

See this blog: http://martypitt.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/custom-json-views-with-spring-mvc-and-jackson/ for an example how to archive a similar (not the same) goal. It also describe one way to register the `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler` (for an other see [Bart´s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22891979/280244))

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Martin J - in general you are right, but: 1) the answer is "use a HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler" (instead a HttpMessageConverter). 2) I have had only a mobile phpne when I was typing this: so there was only two possible ways: not to give an example, or giving a example that is only a link to a blog.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary to

> replace the default RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor with you owner
>   processor

, otherwise the default RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor will take control of handling return value.